# Behaviour of individual terms in Einstein-Smoluchowski fluctuation-dissipation relation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, diffusion, dissipation, fluctuation-dissipation

Consider a bath of Brownian particles at temperature $T$. If we sprinkle some larger particles in this (eg: pollen grains in water or dust motes in air), they'll diffuse with diffusion constant $D$ due to bombardments by the Brownian particles. For the same bombardments, any acceleration of these bigger particles due to an external force will die down to a terminal velocity $v_t=F/\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is a damping coefficient. The relation between their fluctuation and dissipation is given by  a [fluctuation-dissipation equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem):

$\gamma D=k_BT$ [(Einstein-Smoluchowski relation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_%28kinetic_theory%29)

I now have a basic question regarding the behaviour of the individual terms on the left side. Suppose I were to slowly change just the temperature of the bath. That would change the product $\gamma D$. But how would $\gamma$ and $D$ separately change?

Drawing an analogy from the ideal gas state equation $PV = k_BT$, their individual behaviour might depend on the particular process in which I change $T$. So assume that my system (say a bath of water with pollen grains) remains at atmospheric pressure and at the same volume as I just notch up the temperature of the heat bath. How would $\gamma$ and $D$ change then?

Comment: You never told us what $\gamma$ is.

Comment: I did, actually, in the 4th line: $v_t=F/\gamma$ (it's the damping coefficient).

Comment: Yes, but you didn't tell us what it was. I fixed it for you.

Comment: I did, because I wrote the *definition* of $\gamma$, which is a lot more than just the name.

Comment: Writing down an expression that happens to contain a symbol isn't the same as saying what that symbol stands for. Why would you say it is?

Comment: Because if someone asked you what a damping coefficient is, that equation is exactly what you would have to write down. The physics doesn't depend on what it's called, it depends on its quantitative definition and no more, which is exactly what I wrote down.

Comment: Yes, but nobody is going to ask what a damping coefficient is unless you actually say the words "damping coefficient" somewhere in the text. You wrote down a definition but you forgot to say the name of the thing being defined. I asked you what it was, you told me, I edited it into the post. That is the end of the story. There is nothing more to be said.

Comment: Just to clarify why it was unclear: the main issue is that you put the thing being defined on the right-hand side of the equation, and in general it's a good idea to make a note in the text if you do something like that, in order to avoid confusion. The way you originally wrote it, it looked like you were defining $v_t$ in terms of $\gamma$. Because of this I thought $\gamma$ must be related to the viscosity, but I couldn't think of a quantity with the right units, which is why I asked for clarification. It's *really important* to say the names of the things you're defining, in any context.

Answer (score 3):

The temperature-evolution of $D$ and $\gamma$ are still based on models. However, for some fluids these are standard and accurate ones.

For Low Reynold's number, $\gamma$ is proportional to $\eta$, the viscosity of the fluid, by the [Stoke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) $\gamma=6\pi\eta r$.

In the Arrhenius fluid model, $\eta$ drops with temperature if the fluid flow obeys the Arrhenius equation for molecular kinetics:

> $\gamma\propto e^{E_a/RT}$  (See [Temperature-Dependence of Liquid Viscosity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_dependence_of_liquid_viscosity))

$D$ is the final observable that emerges from the other values via the Einstein-Smoluchowski equation $D=k_B T/\gamma$.

For Low Reynold's number, this thus becomes the [Stokes-Einstein equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_%28kinetic_theory%29#Stokes-Einstein_equation) (because Stoke's law can be used): $D=k_B T/6\pi\eta r$, and therefore $D$ depends thus on temperature:

> $D \propto Te^{-E_a/RT}$ (See [Temperature-Dependence of Diffusion Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_diffusivity#Temperature_dependence_of_the_diffusion_coefficient).)